# signing in with external emails on a SAML App configured in Google's admin console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, google-workspace, google-identity

My question is as follows:

can an external user from my organisation be authenticate with a SAML App I have configured the google admin console?

Why I'm confused:

There is the Identity Platform which I have used previously for authenticating google accounts, but this time around I need the associated groups my internal accounts are in which I'm using saml for while still needing external google accounts be authenticated. I have set up a service provider and I can properly handle my internal account authentication and authorisation with the Groups but I get a `403 app not configured for this user` when logging in with a generic gmail email address and I have not found a way to correct this.

So I am looking for guidance on what I can do to correct this or what path to take that I can achieve:

1. internal and external google accounts to perform SSO.
2. Using google's admin console for creating groups to give me a method of authorisation for internal users in groups.

Comment: Did you figure out a solution for this?

Comment: @zed as I understand it, you can't do this with the admin console, you'd need to have the external organization configure a SAML app in their admin console/SAML authority. You provide the details for authentication/authorization with your SAML server, they will provide their authority key for your server to authenticate the SAML requests from their users.